# How to add and activate new language version?

Tags: multilingual

I have added a new language to my Sitecore installation (Control Panel > Localization > Add a new language). In this case I added Spanish.

I have created a new version of my page in Spanish and published.

However, when I view my site from a Spanish IP address, it does not serve the Spanish version. Should it do so?

Apologies - I am not a developer but I understood this functionality should work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is not out of the box. If you want the language to be based on the IP, you can write a language processor that uses the [geo ip information](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/ip_geolocation/ip_geolocation/getting_started_with_sitecore_ip_geolocation_service) (or write your own IP logic). But you will need to write a language processor. There is an old but still very useful post on this here: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/repost-overriding-sitecore-39-s-logic-to-determine-the-context-language

Ootb the language will be determined by:

- the sc_lang query string parameter
- the language prefix in the path in the requested URL
- the language cookie associated with the context site
- or a default language

Edit: just wrote a blog post on my latest experience doing location based language resolving. This might help: https://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2018/05/sitecore-context-language-geo-ip-location.html